# Canvas won't appear in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My canvas wont show in my browser.
I'm guessing the reason is because of some newbie jquery  mistakes. 
The codes below are in two separate folders, Game.html and game.js

Game.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="gameCanvas"> 


    </canvas>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
        <script src="Scripts/game.js" type="text/javascript">  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

game.js:

```
var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$('#gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasWidth);
$('#gameCanvas').attr('height', canvasHeight);

var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

Comment: What do you see in the console? What browser?

Comment: Have you wrapped your game.js code with `$(function(){ .. });` ? If not, try it.

Comment: You should use `$('#gameCanvas').css({'width':canvasWidth,'height': canvasHeight});` instead attr, but probably is not a solution...

Comment: No, he should define the dimension within the html tag like this: `<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600">` to prevent flickr effects.

Comment: I don't understand the use of jQuery here.... http://pastebin.com/Gp3Xm2za

Answer (score 0):

Here is tested your code is working perfectly.

Look in your Scripts folder content files jquery-2.0.3.js and game.js.

the only possibility is error path, look at this.

And what browser are you testing? html5 canvas is then only works in some new browsers.

checked [here](http://caniuse.com/canvas) if your browser does have canvas support

```
Code Equals
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/5JRmu/)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your reference to the script file is correct.  If both html and script are in two different folders, then the reference might need to be:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script src="../Scripts/game.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
```